# Mostrar datos de un ArrayList en un DataTable en Java?

Tags: java

Lo que quiero hacer es mostrar los datos que meto en mi `textBox` en mi pagina primero los mando a una clase llamada personas, los guardo en un `ArrayList` y luego los consulto para ser mostrados por un método REGISTRAR que esta en PersonaBean en un dataTable con el botón registrar. El problema esta que cuando le doy en registrar no me los muestra en la mi página. Coloco el código a continuación!

```
INDEX
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>


                <h:panelGrid columns="3">
                    <h:outputLabel value="Nombre"/>
                    <h:inputText id="txtNombre" value="#{personaBean.persona.nombre}" required="true" label="Nombre requerido"/>
                    <h:message for="txtNombre" style="color: red"/>

                    <h:outputLabel value="Edad"/>
                    <h:inputText id="txtEdad" value="#{personaBean.persona.edad}" required="true" label="(1-18)" >
                        <f:validator validatorId="mayorDeEdad"/>
                    </h:inputText>
                    <h:message for="txtEdad" style="color: red"/>

                    <h:outputLabel value="Sexo"/>
                    <h:inputText id="txtSexo" value="#{personaBean.persona.sexo}" validator="#{personaBean.validar}"/>
                    <h:message for="txtSexo" style="color: red"/>
                </h:panelGrid>

            <h:commandButton actionListener="#{personaBean.registrar()}" value="Registrar"/>
            <h:commandButton actionListener="#{personaBean.registrar()}" value="Registrar SIN VALIDAR" immediate="true"/>    

            <h:dataTable value="#{personaBean.lstPersona}" var="per" rendered="#{personaBean.lstPersona.size() > 0 eq true}">
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputLabel value="Nombre"/>
                    </f:facet>  
                    <h:outputText value="#{per.nombre}"/>
                </h:column>

                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputLabel value="Edad"/>
                    </f:facet>    
                    <h:outputText value="#{per.edad}"/>
                </h:column>

                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputLabel value="Sexo"/>
                    </f:facet>    
                    <h:outputText value="#{per.sexo}"/>
                </h:column>
            </h:dataTable>            
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

CLASE PERSONA

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package clases;

/**
 *
 * @author kali
 */
public class Persona {
    private String nombre;
    private int edad;
    private String sexo;

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public int getEdad() {
        return edad;
    }

    public void setEdad(int edad) {
        this.edad = edad;
    }

    public String getSexo() {
        return sexo;
    }

    public void setSexo(String sexo) {
        this.sexo = sexo;
    }


}

CLASE PERSONA BEAN
package beans;

import clases.Persona;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.enterprise.context.Dependent;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.component.UIInput;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

/**
 *
 * @author kali
 */
@Named(value = "personaBean")
@Dependent
public class PersonaBean {
    private Persona persona = new Persona();
    private List<Persona> lstPersona = new ArrayList();

    public PersonaBean() {
    }

    public Persona getPersona() {
        return persona;
    }

    public void setPersona(Persona persona) {
        this.persona = persona;
    }

    public List<Persona> getLstPersona() {
        return lstPersona;
    }

    public void setLstPersona(List<Persona> lstPersona) {
        this.lstPersona = lstPersona;
    }

    public void registrar(){
        this.lstPersona.add(this.persona);
    }


    public void validar(FacesContext context,UIComponent toValidate, Object value){

    context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

    String texto = (String)value;

    if(!texto.equalsIgnoreCase("M" ) && !texto.equalsIgnoreCase("F")){

            ((UIInput)toValidate).setValid(false);
            context.addMessage(toValidate.getClientId(context), new FacesMessage("Sexo NO VALIDO"));
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@Named(value = "personaBean")
@Dependent
public class PersonaBean {
```

Los `managed beans` tienen definido un `scope` o ámbito que define como se comparte (o no) instancias. En este caso tu tienes definido `@Dependent`, [que significa](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/enterprise/context/Dependent.html)

> - No injected instance of the bean is ever shared between multiple injection points.
> - Any instance of the bean injected into an object that is being created by the container is bound to the lifecycle of the newly created object.
> - When a Unified EL expression in a JSF or JSP page that refers to the bean by its EL name is evaluated, at most one instance of the bean is instantiated. This instance exists to service just a single evaluation of the EL expression. It is reused if the bean EL name appears multiple times in the EL expression, but is never reused when the EL expression is evaluated again, or when another EL expression is evaluated.
> - Any instance of the bean that receives a producer method, producer field, disposer method or observer method invocation exists to service that invocation only.
> - Any instance of the bean injected into method parameters of a disposer method or observer method exists to service the method invocation only.

En este caso interesa el primer y tercer punto, que vienen a decir que si tienes:

```
#{miBean.cantidadAzules + miBean.cantidadRojas}
```

sólo se crea una instancia, pero si tienes

```
#{miBean.cantidadAzules + miBean.cantidadRojas}<br/>
#{miBean.nombre}
```

se crea una instancia para la primera expresión y otra para la segunda.

Si esto es así para accesos al bean en una misma página/petición (`request`), también **en cada petición se crearán beans distintos**, con lo cual tu bean siempre está "recién creado".

La solución es cambiar el `scope` de  `@Dependent` a [`javax.faces.view.@ViewScoped`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/view/ViewScoped.html) (JSF2.2) o [`javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/enterprise/context/SessionScoped.html).

Si más adelante vuelves a tener dudas sobre `scope`s, suele ser util añadir un mensaje de log al constructor para ver dónde (y sobre todo, cuántas veces) se están creando instancias. [Esta pregunta en inglés explica los distintos `scope`s en detalle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope)